# Laravel 8 - form not saving with unique input

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to submit form with two input. One input name is 'name' and second name is 'username' and username is unique. Form not saving when I'm trying to submit. How can I solve this problem?

**My controller is:**

```
public function profileSettingsPost(request $request){

        $request->validate([
            
            'name' => ['nullable','string', 'max:64'],
            'username' => ['nullable','string','max:16','unique:users'],

        ]);
    
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->username = $request->username;

    if($user->save()){

       return redirect()->route('getProfile',['username'=>$user->username]);

    }else{
       return back();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$input = $request->all();
$rules = [
   name' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:64'],
   username' => ['nullable','string','max:16','unique:users,username_column']
];
$massages = [] ;
$fieldNames = [];
$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, $massages, $fieldNames);

if($validation->fails()){
    return redirect()->route('getProfile',['username'=>$user->username]);
}else {
    return back();
}
```

and don't forget to type hint user Model and validation Facade

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```